# Debian Package Creation- How to install configuration files?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, package

I've been really stuck on this minor (I'm sure) issue so any help would be greatly appreciated. I've created a standard ubuntu package with dh_make. The purpose of this package  is to create a package that will set up all the ldap related packages that a system needs including it's configuration.  One of the steps I'm trying to do is to copy over an /etc/ldap.conf file while making a backup of the existing file.  How do I do this?  I tried to create a postinst script that looks essentially like the following, but I'm not clear on how the package stores the files and I get an error saying missing etc/ldap.conf file.  What's the best way to do this?  Here is my postinst script:

`#!/bin/bash -xv`

```
install -v -b etc/ldap.conf /etc/ldap.conf  > /tmp/tst 2>&1
```

Here is my skeleton structure:

```
    root@hqd-clientb-16:~/navldapubuntu-0.1/debian# tree


     ├── changelog
     ├── compat
     ├── control
     ├── copyright
     ├── docs
     ├── etc
        └── ldap.conf
     ├── install
     ├── postinst
     ├── README.Debian
     ├── README.source
     ├── rules
     ├── source
       └── format
     ├── navldapubuntu
       └── etc
     ├── navldapubuntu.debhelper.log
     ├── navldapubuntu.dirs
     └── navldapubuntu.doc-base.EX
```

Here's some additional information of the package I created.

```
    dpkg --contents tnoldapubuntu_0.1-1_all.deb (truncated output)
    ./usr/
    ./usr/share/
    ./usr/share/doc

    ./usr/share/doc/navldapubuntu/
    ./usr/share/doc/navldapubuntu/copyright
    ./usr/share/doc/navldapubuntu/README.Debian
    ./usr/share/doc/navldapubuntu/changelog.Debian.gz
    ./etc/ldap.conf
```

Comment: backup in postinst? maybe in preinst? check file exists: `if [ -f /etc/ldap.conf ] then cp /etc/ldap.conf /etc/ldap.conf.dist fi`, right?

Comment: The problem is not in the logic of the cp.  The problem is that the source /etc/ldap.conf does not exist.  How do I include this in the package so that my postinstall script will see the /etc/ldap.conf file?  I get an error in my script now that states something like: install: cannot stat `/navldap-0.1/debian/etc/ldap.conf': No such file or director

Comment: strangely, you don't have a file in `/etc` and throwing an error that you don't have it in a different directory? script can't run `stat` on file in your package, from which directory you run install?

Comment: I'm sorry..I'm not clear about your comment.  What I'm trying to do is have the file stored within the package (see dpkg --contents above).  After the package creation, I want a file that is within the package to be installed and this file will NOT be local. I'm not clear on how to do this.

Answer (score 8):

There is a special tool that designed for creation of configuration packages: http://debathena.mit.edu/config-packages

Here is a simple template that could be helpful for a quick start.

List of files

- template (directory)
- template/debian (directory)
- template/debian/control
- template/debian/changelog
- template/debian/displace
- template/debian/rules
- template/debian/postinst
- template/debian/install
- template/debian/docs
- template/debian/compat
- template/README
- template/BUILD
- template/files (directory)
- template/files/etc/ldap.conf.mycompanyname

Content

template/debian/control:

```
Source: PACKAGE_NAME
Section: morpho/misc
Priority: optional
Maintainer: MAINTAINER
Build-Depends: debhelper, config-package-dev (>= 5.0~)

Package: PACKAGE_NAME
Architecture: all
Depends: ${misc:Depends}, DEPENDENCY [, DEPENDENCY ...]
Provides: ${diverted-files}
Conflicts: ${diverted-files}
Description: PACKAGE_DESCRIPTION_SHORT
PACKAGE_DESCRIPTION_LONG.
```

template/debian/displace

```
/etc/ldap/ldap.conf.mycompanyname
```

template/debian/install

```
files/* /
```

template/debian/postinst

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e
#DEBHELPER#

POSTINST_SCRIPT
```

template/debian/rules

```
#!/usr/bin/make -f

# Exclude *.svn* from building 
# you probably don't need this if don't use SVN
export DH_ALWAYS_EXCLUDE=.svn

# Core (check http://debathena.mit.edu/config-packages for more information)
%:
        dh $@ --with=config-package

# Prevent dh_installdeb of treating files in /etc as configuration files
# you need this if need configuration files been always rewritten
# even if changed
override_dh_installdeb:
        dh_installdeb
        rm debian/*/DEBIAN/conffiles
```

template/debian/docs

```
README
BUILD
```

And finally you can build this package with the following command:

```
dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc -I.svn
```

Comment: Thanks for providing a full example, that's exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: I found that the displaced file suffix "mycompanyname" needs to to be the package name prefix (e.g. "mycompanyname-ldap-config") with `config-package-dev` 5.1.2

Answer (score 3):

You need to create a "conffiles" file  in the DEBIAN directory, next to the "control" file, and declare /etc/ldap.conf in it. So this file will be automatically considered a configuration file, and changes to it will prompt a "new config file, would you want to overwrite, yadda yadda".

Comment: Thank you so much.  I'm getting an error now when building after creating the conffiles file with /etc/ldap.conf in it.  Also, can a flag be passed to create a backup file of /etc/ldap.conf?  :        dpkg-deb --build debian/navldapubuntu ..
dpkg-deb: error: conffile `/etc/ldap.conf' does not appear in package
dh_builddeb: dpkg-deb --build debian/tnoldapubuntu .. returned exit code 2

Comment: Actually,  the conffiles file looks like it only preserves the file.  I'm looking to have the package include a version of ldap.conf file that installs when I do the apt-get install.  For example: (1) Build package with customized ldap.conf file (2) apt-get install "package name" and this customized ldap.conf will get installed as well.  Hope this makes sense?

Comment: Makes sense, so you should include /etc/ldap.conf  in your  package. What happens if you do?